# Why the date of the file generated by hexo is 1970

Tags: time, hexo

I’m using hexo to build a blog recently, but the posts generated by `hexo -g` have date of 1970:

```
(base) root@DESKTOP-7SU7LQD:/mnt/d/Blog_2# ls source/_posts/
hello-world.md
(base) root@DESKTOP-7SU7LQD:/mnt/d/Blog_2# hexo g
...
INFO  Generated: 1970/01/01/hello-world/index.html
INFO  37 files generated in 2.65 s
```

```
(base) root@DESKTOP-7SU7LQD:/mnt/d/Blog_2# ls public/
1970  404.html  about  archives  categories  css  img  index.html  js  lib  links  local-search.xml  tags  xml
```

How can I handle this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show a source file, a post?

Without further details, it's very likely a missing [front matter](https://hexo.io/docs/front-matter)
It is not mandatory for "compilation" but it may cause issues later when files are processed from Markdown to Yaml to Html.

It will help to separate files

```yaml
---
title: Hello World
date: 2013/7/13 20:46:25
---
```

---

Another solution would be to use https://hexo.io/docs/variables#Page-Variables : momentjs' date_updated page variable
which seems to be more likely to the point
[enter link description here](https://hexo.io/docs/configuration.html)

You would need to use `updated_option: 'date'`

EDIT: 2nd solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, when I set the date in md file, It is normal. But according to the hexo ,when I don't set the date, the default is the time I created the md file (however I got 1970). Here is my source file (in google drive): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sE-BWf4m5Lw9ARSYR_epOsZk0uBhg_yi/view?usp=sharing ; and I still have the same problem when I change another computer.

Comment: I have this behavior too when generating from md straight without front matter

Comment: Into the basic config for posts /hexo/scaffold/post.md
You can see a "date" variable. So I think if you use the (assumed) most common workflow by using hexo-CLI, then, the date would be added. However by copy pasting files into `source ` folder, there won't be any date data added to text, unless main config can overwrite that, but so far I didn't find any config option to overwrite date... As a workaround you could prepend `title: {{ title }}
date: {{ date }}
`
EDIT: hexo is using moment.js for date, you would have to use `updated_option`